# JQuery / AJAX file upload firing once

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, function

I've got the following function:

```
$('#userfile').change(function() {
    $.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: 'control/upload/go',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'userfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
            if(data.status != 'error') {
                $('.input_response').val(data.filename);
            }
            $('.response').text(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it won't fire more than once without a complete page refresh.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Does the under change function fire multiple times. Also I have the feeling that it proxies through a iFrame depending on the plugin you use because in most slightly older browsers ajax file uploads are not supported.

Comment: Is the success function throwing an untrapped error?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using $(document).on(); - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code:

```
jQuery('#userfile').live('change', function()
{

jQuery.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: 'control/upload/go',
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'userfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, status) {
            if(data.status != 'error') {
                jQuery('.input_response').val(data.filename);
            }
            jQuery('.response').text(data.msg);
        }
    });
});
```